# Redirect to default method if CodeIgniter method doesn't exists.

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, redirect, methods

I am using CodeignIter and am looking to for a way to write a custom handling routine for a single controller when a called method does not exist.

Lets say you call `www.website.com/components/login`

In the `components` controller, there is not a method called `login`, so instead of sending a 404 error, it would simply default to another method called `default`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a solution. If you have `Components` controller and the flilename `components.php`. Write following code...

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Components extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $method)) {
            $this->$method($params);
        } else {
            $this->test_default();
        }
    }

    // this method is exists
    public function test_method()
    {
        echo "Yes, I am exists.";
    }

    // this method is exists
    public function test_another($param1 = '', $param2 = '')
    {
        echo "Yes, I am with " . $param1 . " " . $param2;
    }

    // not exists - when you call /compontents/login
    public function test_default()
    {
        echo "Oh!!!, NO i am not exists.";
    }

}
```

Since `default` is PHP reserved you cannot use it so instead you can write your own default method like here `test_default`. This will automatically checks if method exists in your class and redirect accordingly. It also support parameters. This work perfectly for me. You can test yourself. Thanks!!